# mmap limitation on 32 and 64 bit android system

Tags: android, operating-system, filesystems

mmap limitation on 32 and 64 bit android system, if a 32 bit android device have more than 3 GB RAM memory is it possible to mmap 2.5 GB file at once? assuming continuous memory is available. I'm trying to allocate mmap for 2.5 gb file, it works on 64 bit device with arm64-v8a, but I get no memory if I try doing same in 32 bit device armeabi-v7a, even though I have required free continuous space.

EDIT: Added the map of the process, here you can see there is 2.7 GB of space after Heap.

```
00008000-000b7000 r-xp 00000000 00:02 12817      /sbin/adbd
000b7000-000bb000 r--p 000ae000 00:02 12817      /sbin/adbd
000bb000-000bc000 rw-p 000b2000 00:02 12817      /sbin/adbd
000bc000-000be000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
000be000-000bf000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
000bf000-000c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
ad381000-ad382000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread stack guard page]
ad382000-ad480000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:478]
ad480000-ae800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:libc_malloc]
ae800000-aea00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:libc_malloc]
aea02000-aea03000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread stack guard page]
aea03000-aeb01000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:476]
aeb01000-aeb02000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread stack guard page]
aeb02000-aec00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:475]
aec00000-aec80000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:libc_malloc]
aecc1000-aece1000 r--s 00000000 00:0d 14019      /dev/__properties__/u:object_r:debug_prop:s0
aece1000-aece2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread stack guard page]
aece2000-aede0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:474]
aede0000-aee00000 r--s 00000000 00:0d 14013      /dev/__properties__/u:object_r:shell_prop:s0
aee00000-aef00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:libc_malloc]
aef0e000-aef0f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread signal stack guard page]
aef0f000-aef11000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread signal stack]
aef11000-aef12000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread signal stack guard page]
aef12000-aef14000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread signal stack]
aef14000-aef15000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread signal stack guard page]
aef15000-aef17000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread signal stack]
aef17000-aef18000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread signal stack guard page]
aef18000-aef1a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread signal stack]
aef1a000-aef3a000 r--s 00000000 00:0d 14003      /dev/__properties__/u:object_r:default_prop:s0
aef3a000-aef3b000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:atexit handlers]
aef3b000-aef5b000 r--s 00000000 00:0d 14030      /dev/__properties__/properties_serial
aef5b000-aef5c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread signal stack guard page]
aef5c000-aef5e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:thread signal stack]
bed80000-beda1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
bee73000-bee74000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [sigpage]
ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]
```

Comment: *even though I have required free continuous space*  How do you know you have enough free continuous memory in your process's address space?

Comment: I pulled proc/self/maps

Comment: Could you post the map for one of your 32-bit processes?  Linux in general reserves process addresses at 3GB and higher for the kernel mappings.  I'm not sure if that applies to 32-bit ARM or not.  Here's the Red Had explanation:  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/sect-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Growing_the_Oracle_SGA_to_2.7_GB_in_x86_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_2.1_Without_VLM-Linux_Memory_Layout.html

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have added the map, I went through the page you shared. But I'm not sure if the allocation of kernel and user space is same in case of 32 bit ARM

Comment: Given that map, I'd agree that a 2.5GB `mmap()` *should* work.  What's the value of `errno` after your `mmap()` attempt fails?  What does [`getrlimit()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) return for the value of `RLIMIT_AS` and `RLIMIT_DATA`?  You might want to experiment with trying `mmap()` in a loop, starting at 2.5GB and decreasing the size of the memory you want by, say, 1MB on each loop.  Loop until the `mmap()` succeeds, then see what the process map looks like.

Comment: Mapping works for any value less then 1.9 GB, errno returned was ENOMEM

Comment: Hi @AndrewHenle I used sysinfo struct to get these values, before I try mmap, 
Total RAM: 3783131136
Free RAM: 3542626304
Shared Ram: 8671232
Buffer RAM: 8421376
Total Swap: 0
FreeSwap: 0

Comment: It looks like you may be running into a 2GB limit of some sort.  The check the resource limits from `getrlimit()`.  From a bash prompt, if you have that, `ulimit -a` will show you all your current limits.

Comment: Hi @AndrewHenle,  used getrlimit() and here are the values, RLIMIT_AS Default value is : 4294967295
RLIMIT_AS MAX value is : 4294967295
RLIMIT_DATA Default value is : 4294967295
RLIMIT_DATA MAX value is : 4294967295  The data says the limit is 4GB which is the size of the ram.